# Web service call timer

Tags: php

I have a PHP script that sends a request to a web service via soap.  I expect to get a response back in just a few seconds, but if I do not receive a response within 30 seconds I need to send another request voiding my first request.

Any suggestions on the best way to handle this timer feature? Should I be looking at PHP's set`_time`_limit setting? Looking for any insight or general ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Trying to simplify this as much as possible.  Could I simply put the first call on a page with a header refresh set to 30 seconds?  If my script gets a response before then, I set my script to redirect to the next page I want.  If no response after the 30 seconds, the header redirect can jump to the page with the void request?

Comment: You are speaking about stuff that happens in the client (headers) not on the server.

Comment: Look, this is a classic event driven programming. You need a listener and you need a caller. Both working/awake at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Found this on the web and seems like a step in the right direction...

a feature -> setting a connection timeout

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("connection_timeout"=>5));The connection_timeout option defines a timeout in seconds for the connection to the SOAP service. This option does not define a timeout for services with slow responses. To limit the time to wait for calls to finish the default_socket_timeout setting is available.

Answer (score 0):

If we only had multi threading....
My approach (although you can do async calls with CURL) would be to write a script that manages this process. This script would do:

1. Using shell/cron/async javascript (from the client side)/async call using CURL to  activate the calling script.
2. Check every few seconds if the calling script returned an answer (answer is saved to memory/disk by the calling script, which also serves as a flag->I finished)
3. 30 seconds passed - kill the current instance of the calling script, instantiate another calling script.

This is a very crude description, and the finer details should be defined better.

Comment: Restored your -1 to zero. Legitimate answer. I would do it through Cron as well.